# Charge/Stripe and "Missing required param: exp_month."

Tags: templating, plugin-charge

I'm working on getting charge to take donations and have set up my Expiration date field the same as in the demos.

```
<div class="col-6">
    <label for="cardExpiry" class="form-label">Expiration Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-stripe="exp"  id="cardExpiry" placeholder="mm / yy" required>
</div>
```

However on form submission (in test mode) I see this error.

> Missing required param: exp_month.

Not sure how to resolve this. Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this resolved by official support.

```
When using the combined date input you'll need to include the exp_month and exp_year inputs as hidden fields in the form.
```

And here's the working hidden fields:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="cardExpMonth" value="" data-stripe="exp_month">
  <input type="hidden" name="cardExpYear" value=""data-stripe="exp_year">
```